# How to get PyDev to understand tab characters (for Python 2.7)?

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I have tried to get `Eclipse` (with Python package) to understand tab as **"tabulation"**, `i.e., their original/historical/Python2.7` meaning:
`tab char = tabulation = move to the next 8th column` (no matter how many spaces or other characters are present to the left).

The original meaning of `moving to then next 8th column` is what Python 2.7 understands and it is necessary to see correct indentation for (badly written) legacy code that **mixes spaces and tabs**.
For example:
=8 times  =

`Eclipse` seems to only be able to `replace tabs with spaces and vice versa` but I could not find any option to have `Eclipse` interpret the tab character as tabulation. Replacing a tab with a fixed number of spaces is going to break things even more.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's no special support for that inside of PyDev -- what's supported is either only tabs or only spaces.

My suggestion is reindenting the code appropriately to use only spaces or only tabs (maybe you can use https://pypi.org/project/Reindent/ to fix it for you -- or a code formatter such as https://github.com/ambv/black if you're up to changing more of the code).

Answer (score 0):

That is very bad because Python 2.7 supports the (stupid) mix of tabs and spaces and there is (badly written) legacy code with the ugly mixture.
That is why I have stopped using Eclipse for Python 2.7.